Avoid playing 2 videos in HTML on bunny.net
I use bunny.net to stream videos on my customer websites. I would like to know if there is a way that I cannot play 2 videos simultaneously. The thing is that I like to have the buttons enabled on the videos, so when the user plays 1 video then the other video on the sabe page, the 2 videos play simultaneously.
This is an example of 1 video of my page
<div style="position:relative;padding-top:56.25%;"><iframe src="https://iframe.mediadelivery.net/embed/236449/48e3c908-1e7f-4ede-a9b1-25d29502c62e?autoplay=false&loop=false&muted=false&preload=false&responsive=true" loading="lazy" style="border:0;position:absolute;top:0;height:100%;width:100%;" allow="accelerometer;gyroscope;autoplay;encrypted-media;picture-in-picture;" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe></div>

Regards
I tried preload false and autoplay false, It didn't work, bunny.net support could not give me support for this.
Regards

Can you make a test page (or show code) with this "two videos that play at same time" problem? Use the Edit option to add new code, or put link in comments for a web page that shows the problem.
